# Change react-native rootView color to black?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I was looking through AppDelegate.m file in my iOS project, there is this line:

```
rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]
                              initWithRed:1.0f
                              green:1.0f
                              blue:1.0f
                              alpha:1];
```

I believe this sets iOS root view to white by default? I was trying to google this notation, but wasn't able to find anything. How would one alter rgb values so it is black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

https://moduscreate.com/blog/changing-the-react-native-rootview-background-color-ios-and-android/